# Can't create Json reader

Tags: java, json, tomcat, server

I'm trying to read Json object (which are user login and pass for android app) on the server side but during creation, I got some errors.. Have no idea what ever that means

```
UserModel uM = new UserModel();    
try {
                System.out.println("\nTrying to save...");
                InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
                JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(inputStream); // this is where error occurs
    //            JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
    //            reader.close();
    //            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("login").toString());
    //            uM.setLogin(jsonObject.get("login").toString());
    //            uM.setPassword(jsonObject.get("password").toString());
    //            System.out.println(uM.toString());
    //            userDAO.save(uM);
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Server log: **@EDIT** I only posted warnings, now its full log, probably would be much more helpful

```
19-Jun-2017 21:36:34.490 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
19-Jun-2017 21:36:34.617 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19-Jun-2017 21:36:46.631 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-mvc'
19-Jun-2017 21:36:57.007 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:94)
    at javax.json.Json.createReader(Json.java:220)
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController.register(AndroidUserController.java:146)
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$448b2d05.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f920f9fc_2.register(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**@EDIT 2**

I add part of my android activity which is sending the Json to the server. Did I miss something here?

```
JSONObject newUser = new JSONObject();
        try {
            newUser.put("login", login.toString());
            newUser.put("password", password.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("USER DO ZAPISANIA W BAZIE: " + newUser.toString());
        JsonObjectRequest urlAccStringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlAcc, newUser, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        System.out.println("Good morning " + login.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterIndividualActivity.this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        queueAcc.add(urlAccStringRequest);

        queueAcc.start();
    }
```

Comment: That log looks truncated.

Comment: @Carcigenicate well, thats what I get

Comment: I can post a screen shot if you want, but that would be exactly the same

Comment: No, it's ok. The top of the trace just looks like it's missing. It doesn't say the error. Did you kill it while it was writing?

Comment: @Carcigenicate do you mean reader.close()? Yes, I tried it - nothing changes

Comment: your logcat is missing it's head.

Comment: guys, you are right, gonna edit my question

Comment: Why is this tagged with `android`, when you're debugging a server-side problem?

Comment: @LarsH well, gonna put my android avtivity here to show the connection between that

Comment: If the server-side code is unable to find a GlassFish JsonProviderImpl class, that would have nothing to do with the Android client.